# Match two criteria and create tibble of matching pairs

Tags: r

I'm really stuck here and have no clue how to come further except that the code should be in the `tidyverse` package.

```
Name       City    ID
Anne       NY      2
Simon      LA      2
James      LON     2
Charlie    SA      2
Simon      LA      2
Anne       URE     2
Jason      HAM     2
Simon      LA      2
"With 800 more rows
```

I want to identify citys with matching criteria, as we can see above LA matches with Simon and there are more matches along the rows not mentioned here. I would like to create a tibble where I can identify the matching pairs (in other words all citys that have more than 1 matches with a unique name).

I would highly appreciate if anyone had any clue how to solve this task.

Comment: appreciate if you can update your post with your expected output format (as it is not clear from the description)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `n_distinct` to filter those cases

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(City) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(Name) > 1) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    distinct(City, Name)
```

---

Or get the `distinct` by 'City' and 'Name' and then `filter` based on the `count` of 'City'

```
distinct(df1, City, Name) %>%
   group_by(City) %>%
   filter(n() > 1)
```